# Does a tool exist to visualize custom OSM changesets?

Tags: openstreetmap

I have custom changesets, not yet applied to the OSM map. I want to be able to visualize them before uploading them. A tool like achavi (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Achavi#Changeset_Viewer) is what I am looking for. Achavi however only works with history from OSM and not with custom changesets, not yet applied to OSM.

Answer (score 2):

Achavi can visualize any OSM change file, you only need to drag and drop your custom file onto the page. Data doesn't have to be uploaded to OSM. However, as you don't describe how you create your custom file, you might have to tweak it to make it work, i.e. you need to take care of that step yourself.

See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Achavi#Augmented_Delta_.28.22adiff.22.29_Viewer:

*Achavi can also display the results of your custom Augmented Diff query. Drag&drop a file onto the map or use the url parameter*

*https://overpass-api.de/achavi/?url=the_urlencoded_path_to_the_xml*